# Join dictionaries so that previous dictionary names are now 2nd layer keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to organize new dictionaries based on the results of a df.groupby('fruits').  I now have dictionaries setup like the following,

```
print(type(flavors))
<class 'dict'>

print(flavors)
{'apples':['crisp', 'tart'],
 'oranges':['citrusy','juicy', 'sour'],
 'bananas':['sweet']}

print(colors)
{'apples':['red', 'green'],
 'oranges':['orange','orange', 'rotten'],
 'bananas':['yellow']}

print(farms)
{'apples':['upstate orchard', 'dreamy estates'],
 'oranges':['crop culture','sandy bay', 'heartland'],
 'bananas':['horticulture heros']}
```

How could I join them in a new dictionary like the following?

```
print(fruits_dict)
{'apples': {'flavors': ['crisp', 'tart'],
            'colors': ['red', 'green'],
            'farms': ['upstate orchard', 'dreamy estates'] },
'oranges': {'flavors': ['citrusy','juicy', 'sour'],
            'colors': ['orange','orange', 'rotten'],
            'farms': ['crop culture','sandy bay', 'heartland'] },
'bananas': {'flavors': ['sweet'],
            'colors': ['yellow'],
            'farms': ['horticulture heros'] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dicts = {'flavors' : flavors, 'colors': colors, 'farms' : farms}
result = {key: { k : dicts[k][key] for k in dicts} for key in flavors}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example with dict comprehension how to get your output:

```
flavors = {
    "apples": ["crisp", "tart"],
    "oranges": ["citrusy", "juicy", "sour"],
    "bananas": ["sweet"],
}


colors = {
    "apples": ["red", "green"],
    "oranges": ["orange", "orange", "rotten"],
    "bananas": ["yellow"],
}


farms = {
    "apples": ["upstate orchard", "dreamy estates"],
    "oranges": ["crop culture", "sandy bay", "heartland"],
    "bananas": ["horticulture heros"],
}

out = {
    k: {
        "flavors": flavors.get(k, []),
        "colors": colors.get(k, []),
        "farms": farms.get(k, []),
    }
    for k in (flavors.keys() & colors.keys() & farms.keys())
}

from pprint import pprint

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'apples': {'colors': ['red', 'green'],
            'farms': ['upstate orchard', 'dreamy estates'],
            'flavors': ['crisp', 'tart']},
 'bananas': {'colors': ['yellow'],
             'farms': ['horticulture heros'],
             'flavors': ['sweet']},
 'oranges': {'colors': ['orange', 'orange', 'rotten'],
             'farms': ['crop culture', 'sandy bay', 'heartland'],
             'flavors': ['citrusy', 'juicy', 'sour']}}
```